# PHP caching include file

Tags: php, caching

I have the following test code in test.php:

```
<?php
$step = $_GET['step'];
switch($step) {
  case 1:
    include 'foo.php';   # line 5
    file_put_contents('foo.php', '<?php print "bar\\n"; ?>');
    header('Location: test.php?step=2');
  break;
  case 2:
    print "step 2:\n";
    include 'foo.php';
  break;
}
?>
```

foo.php initially has the following content:

```
<?php print "foo\n"; ?>
```

When I call test.php?step=1 in my browser I would expect the following output:

```
step 2:
bar
```

But I get this output:

```
step 2:
foo
```

When I comment out the include in line 5, I get the desired result. The conclusion is, that PHP caches the content of foo.php. When I reload the page with step=2 I also get the desired result.

Now... why is this and how to avoid this?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: I'd guess that you never get redirected to `?step=2` since you are print'ing data before sending the `Location` header (which should cause an error).

Comment: It would not work with commented out line 5 if foo.php would not be overwritten. I also looked into foo.php... It is modified.

Comment: cOle2: It would not print "step 2:" if it would not get redirected!

Comment: britter: I use PHP 5.5.9

Comment: If you still believe it is caching, you should check if OpCache is enabled. opcache.enable=0 in your php.ini.

Comment: Though I would imagine it is not good practice to alter an included file after you have included it.

Comment: Thanks britter! opcache.enable=0 did the trick.

Comment: britter: Well, good practice... I develop a PHP tool with a web installer. This installer writes the database configuration into the config file and then has to access this database - reading the config from the config file. Maybe I find a cleaner solution...

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you use OPcache, `opcache.enable = 0` works.

A more efficient method is to use

```
opcache_invalidate ( string $script [, boolean $force = FALSE ] )
```

This will remove the cached version of the script from memory and force PHP to recompile.

Answer (score 5):

Note that `opcache_invalidate` is not always available. So it is better to check if it exists. Also, you should check both of `opcache_invalidate` and `apc_compile_file`.

Following function will do everything:

```
    public static function clearCache($path){
        if (function_exists('opcache_invalidate') && strlen(ini_get("opcache.restrict_api")) < 1) {
            opcache_invalidate($path, true);
        } elseif (function_exists('apc_compile_file')) {
            apc_compile_file($path);
        }
    }
```